# SQL Update Maria DB with Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement

Please help.. I have search it. But I still don't know where is my fault. Maybe I just miss something.

Here is the error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ID_JABATAN=?, TANGGAL_MASUK=?, TANGGAL_KELUAR=?, ID_JENIS_KARYAWAN=? WHERE ID' at line 1
```

And this is my code :

```
    try {
        DBConnection knk = new DBConnection();
        Connection conn = knk.bukaKoneksi();
        String sql = "UPDATE KARYAWAN SET NAMA_KARYAWAN=?, ID_JABATAN=?, TANGGAL_MASUK=?, TANGGAL_KELUAR=?, ID_JENIS_KARYAWAN=? WHERE ID_KARYAWAN=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, karyawan.getNamaKaryawan());
        ps.setInt(2, karyawan.getIdJabatan());
        ps.setDate(3, karyawan.getTanggalMasuk());
        ps.setDate(4, karyawan.getTanggalKeluar());
        ps.setInt(5, karyawan.getIdJenisKaryawan());
        ps.setInt(6, karyawan.getIdKaryawan());

        int hasil = ps.executeUpdate(sql);
        return hasil > 0;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

And the column of the table :
[image: table column]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int hasil = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3):

remove the Parameter from `int hasil = ps.executeUpdate(sql);`

if you call it with Parameter, the query will be executet, not the prepared Statement.

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()):

> int executeUpdate(String sql)
>                    throws SQLException
>
> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
>   SQL DDL statement.  Note:This method cannot be called on a
>   PreparedStatement or CallableStatement. Parameters:sql - an SQL Data
>   Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or
>   DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL
>   statement.Returns:either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation
>   Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return
>   nothingThrows:SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this
>   method is called on a closed Statement, the given SQL statement
>   produces a ResultSet object, the method is called on a
>   PreparedStatement or CallableStatementSQLTimeoutException - when the
>   driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by the
>   setQueryTimeout method has been exceeded and has at least attempted to
>   cancel the currently running Statement

---

> int executeUpdate()
>                     throws SQLException
>   Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement. Returns:either (1) the row count for SQL Data
>   Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements
>   that return nothingThrows:SQLException - if a database access error
>   occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL
>   statement returns a ResultSet objectSQLTimeoutException - when the
>   driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by the
>   setQueryTimeout method has been exceeded and has at least attempted to
>   cancel the currently running Statement