# Select statement in Java terminates with an error

Tags: java

As I'm finding my way slowly in Java , I'm facing a runtime error when my program is executed..
I'm doing this coding in a select statement …
i get an error code that using  "?" this way is not accept in MariaDB syntax!!
How to solve this issue ….
note that UserName is defined as avariable in the prog.

Thanks

Here's my Code:

```
  String sql = "select Username , Userpassword from Users where Username where        Username = ?";
  statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  statement.setString(1, UserName);
  statement.executeQuery(sql);
  while (statement.getResultSet().next()){
  // ...
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101254/sql-update-maria-db-with-prepared-statement

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong

Answer (score 2):

```
where Username where Username = ?
```

Your SQL query is invalid. You have a `where` clause twice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The alternative is to answer in the comments, which is also frowned upon. I made this a community wiki because I don't want the rep for it.

Comment: `PreparedStatement#executeQuery` does _not_ take any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems that I can see.  First, as @Michael pointed out, you have two `WHERE` clauses.  Maybe this is just a copying error, or maybe this is verbatim what your code is.  In either case, it's wrong, and your query should have just one `WHERE` clause.  The other problem is that you are making the following call to execute the query:

```
statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

[`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) does *not* take any parameters; just call it with no parameters.  So here is the suggestion I would make for you:

```
String sql = "SELECT Username, Userpassword FROM Users WHERE Username = ?";
statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, UserName);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    // process a row
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing code here, problem is solved, as you said it was a syntax error from me typing the statement, and i've learned something new from you, thanks again...